# Adding a rows corresponding column to a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table constructed like so, I find with these types of normalized data it can be hard to quickly see which column has the highest value:

[Test dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzXoO.png)

The code is `test = pd.DataFrame({'0 to 4': [0.031, 0.23, 0.13], '5 to 9':[0.32, 0.142, 0.532], '10 to 14': [0.24, 0.131, 0.564]}, index=['Barking and Dagenham', 'Barnet', 'Bexley'])`

What I am trying to do is find the maximum value of each row and put the corresponding column name into a new column. Like so:
[Result dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwQrR.png)

I've tried lambda and some other methods but I'm a bit stumped right now, any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: It's better to paste the text representation of a dataframe into your question than an image of the notebook graphic.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html).

```py
test['max'] = test.idxmax(axis='columns')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
test['max'] = test.T.idxmax()
```

Comment: Actually, @Imre Kerr's answer is nicer.